# Installing msxml6 64-bit with wine

Tags: wine, 64-bit

I'm trying to install a software which relies on msxml6, and is only provided in a 64bit version (so I can't use the 32-bit msxml6 provided by winetricks).

I downloaded [msxml6 from microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988), and ran it with wine. The installation aborts mid-way saying "installation was interrupted". Here's the debugging log:

```
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"Wdsfpca_AddRefcountMsxml.86F857F6_A743_463D_B2FE_98CB5F727E09" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this? Thanks in advanced

Wine version is 1.7.26 (latest beta), and configured for Windows 7. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple - using wine64 instead of wine, like so:

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix wine64 msiexec /i /path/to/msxml6_x64.msi
```

Comment: You deserve a million thanks for this! I still don't fully get why it works, but I faced a similar issue when trying to install the latest x64 version of WinDbg from [here](http://www.codemachine.com/downloads.html). Running `wine64 msiexec /i Desktop/X64\ Debuggers\ And\ Tools-x64_en-us.msi /qn` made it work instantly. I am guessing there are two versions of msiexec and the x64 one is invoked only through wine64...

Answer (score 0):

When you need to install x64 software with wine just execute following command

> $ wine64 msiexec /i SOFTWARE_NAME.msi

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe it will be useful for some one because I had the same problem and commands mentioned above did not work for me - I had to use this command:

WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=/home/xxxxx/.wine wine64 msiexec /i windowsprogram.msi